# How does the nUnit PairwiseAttribute compare to Sequential and Combinatoral attributes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

How does the nUnit PairwiseAttribute compare to Sequential and Combinatoral attributes? I am failing to see there difference as the documentation on this is very poor and unfortunately I cannot test the attribute as it is not supported in the current alpha release.